# Apply Coupon code to QUOTE with external script Magento

Tags: magento-1

i want to apply coupon code from external script, that will set code and discount amount to quote and final result will be saved quote with new total. I have done following but not saving quote.

```
        $quoteid = "53701";
    $couponCode = "Discount99";
    $oCoupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon')->load(trim($couponCode), 'code');
    $oRule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($oCoupon->getRuleId());

    if($oRule->getRuleId() && $oRule->getRuleId() > 0){
        try{
            $quoteObj = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setCouponCode($oCoupon)->load($quoteid);
            $quoteObj->setTotalsCollectedFlag(true)
                ->collectTotals()
                ->save();
            $returndata["success"] = "1";
            $returndata["message"] = "Coupon Applied Successfully";
            $returndata["data"]["discount_amount"] = $oRule->getDiscountAmount();
        }catch (Exception $e){
            $returndata["success"] = "0";
            $returndata["message"] = "Cart Coupon update Failed";
            $returndata["data"] = null;
        }
    }else{
        $returndata["success"] = "0";
        $returndata["message"] = "Invalid Coupon";
        $returndata["data"] = null;
    }
    echo json_encode($returndata);
    exit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this following way..

```
$quoteid = '53703';
$couponCode = "cvpcode2013";

$oCoupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon')->load(trim($couponCode), 'code');
$oRule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($oCoupon->getRuleId());

if($oRule->getRuleId() && $oRule->getRuleId() > 0){
    try{
        $quote = $this->_getQuote($quoteid,Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId());
        $quote->setCouponCode($couponCode);
        $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();
        $quote->collectTotals();
        $quote->save();
    }catch (Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}else{
    // invalid coupon
}

// create new function 

protected function _getQuote($quoteId, $store = null)
{

        $quote = Mage::getModel("sales/quote");
        if (!(is_string($store) || is_integer($store))) {
            $quote->loadByIdWithoutStore($quoteId);
        } else {
            $storeId = $store;

            $quote->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->load($quoteId);
        }
        if (is_null($quote->getId())) {
            $this->_fault('quote_not_exists');
        }

        return $quote;
}
```